# Manipulate visualization order on action script 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3

i'm making a simple isometric city builder using action script 3.0.
the concept is like age of empires, so when I push a button a shape will be created and it will follow the cursor until i'll click again on the stage and in this way an house will be placed.
but I've some problems with the order of visualization when more house collide between them.

Answer (score 0):

You want to sort the sprites from back to front when a new item is added, here is some sample code that does that.

```
private function sortItems():void
{
    var sprites:Array = [];
    for (var i:int = 0; i < map.numChildren; ++i) {
        var c:DisplayObject = map.getChildAt(i);
        sprites.push(c);
    }

    sortSprites(sprites);
}

private function sortSprites(sprites:Array):void
{
    sprites.sort(sortCompare);

    var index:int = 0;
    for (var j:int = 0; j < sprites.length; j++) {
        index = map.getChildIndex(sprites[j]);
        if (index != j)
            map.setChildIndex(sprites[j], j);
    }
}

private function sortCompare(a:DisplayObject, b:DisplayObject):int
{
    return ((a.y + a.height) - (b.y + b.height));
}
```

Comment: It says :1120: Access of undefined property map.                                                                                                var c:DisplayObject = map.getChildAt(i);

Comment: I haven't use this property before, can you explain me what does map property do?I'm using Adobe cs3

Comment: `map` is just a random variable name I picked, it should be the display container where you add your sprites.